# How do I execute a command after pushing a button while also closing the window with the button in python (with tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically I want to execute the command as seen below and also close the window with the 2 buttons (in either case). The command just sets the variable self.switch to True or False, so if there is a neater way of doing this rather than writing a new method for each of those, that would also be nice.

```
def switchButton(self):
    top = Tk()
    self.a = Button(top,text="Switch", command=self.switchTrue())
    self.a.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.b = Button(top,text="Don't switch", command=self.switchFalse())
    self.b.pack(side=RIGHT)
    top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in a new method *is* the neat way of doing things- you'd probably make the `command=lambda:self.switchTo([value])`, with [value] being True or False that you would like to swap to. You would have to pass `top` into the function as well, so you can `destroy` it.

Doing this `destruction` with `Tk()` is (normally) bad practice, as `Tk()` creates a Tcl/Tk interpreter- you really just want to instantiate it once and `hide` it typically.